# SSAS - Sum of Top or Bottom

Tags: sum, ssas, mdx

```
SELECT  
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON COLUMNS  
 ,Tail  
  (  
    [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS  
   ,2  
  ) ON ROWS  
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Above MDX query gives me output as :

> Year     Internet Sales Amount
>
> CY 2003  $9,791,060.30
>
> CY 2004  $9,770,899.74

I understood how this query worked but I want to create Calculated measure in a cube which will always give me sum of bottom 2 years. How to do this? I am a newbie to SSAS. I am good at designing simple measures and dimensions but when it comes to using MDX, I am mostly stuck.

PS: I tried using TopCount, BottomCount etc but here I want to order by "Year", which is a dimension.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Parry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query calculates a measure for sum the the last 2 years of the Date dimension:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Sales from the last 2 Years]
    AS Aggregate( Tail( [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].Members, 2)
                , [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
                )

SELECT { [Measures].[Sales from the last 2 Years]
       } ON COLUMNS
     , { Tail( [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].Members, 2)
       } ON ROWS
    FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Other interesting query, would be calculating a measure for the sum of each year and its previous:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Sales from 2 years]
    AS Aggregate( { [Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember.PrevMember
                  : [Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember }
                , [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
                )

SELECT { [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
       , [Measures].[Sales from 2 years]
       } ON COLUMNS
     , NON EMPTY
       { [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year]
       } ON ROWS
    FROM [Adventure Works]
```

It does a sum, because the aggregation type of the measure `[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]` is `Sum`, and the `Aggregate` function aggregates according to the measure's aggregation type.

- [Key Concepts in MDX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144884.aspx)
- [Aggregate function reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145524.aspx)

MDX is a hard topic to grasp; if you're starting out, I recommend you read the book [MDX Solutions, 2nd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471748080).

Comment: Thanks a lot Gonsalu. I tried to put that in practice. But I am facing another issue here.. I must use NONEMPTY around the dimension and somehow that doesnt work.... Pasting the practical code here... WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Signposting - Stop smoking service for 2 yrs]
    AS Aggregate(  Tail([Vw LSOA Hierarchy].[LSOA CODE].Members,2)
                , [Measures].[Signposting - Stop smoking service]
                )

SELECT { [Measures].[Signposting - Stop smoking service for 2 yrs]
       } ON COLUMNS
     , {[Vw LSOA Hierarchy].[LSOA CODE]
       } ON ROWS
    FROM [KPI]